# Regex out to variable and print the variable

Tags: bash, shell

In Bash / shell script 
What is the correct way to Assign a Regex Output to a variable 
I tried the below script but a simple Regex output, which is a string is not getting assigned to the variable

```
 # Assigning some Regex "outPut" to a Variable var1
 var1=$ ps -A | grep 300 |  awk '{ print $4 }'
 var2=Variable2
 var3=Variable3
 echo
 #Now Printing the values stored in the variable
 echo "Value of Var1 is"
 echo ""$var1""
 echo "Value of Var2 is"
 echo ""$var2""
 echo "Value of Var3 is"
 echo ""$var3""
 echo
```

and on executing it.. the output i get is 
sh variablePrint.sh 
zeitgeist-daemo

Value of Var1 is

Value of Var2 is
Variable2
Value of Var3 is
Variable3

Can some one help me tell how to assign the regex output to the variable and how to reuse the variable (all in bash/shell script)

Comment: The declaration of the variable in the first line of the code is incorrect. You have to enclose the commands within back quotes(` `).
Also, remove the $ sign while declaring var1

Comment: You don't need `grep` with `awk`: `awk '/300/ {print $4}'`.

Answer (score 0):

Enclose the command to run in a command substitution.

```
var1=$(ps -A | grep 300 |  awk '{ print $4 }')
```

Comment: They aren't backquotes.

Comment: The original answer was edited. My ans was with the back quotes.

      var1=`ps -A | grep 300 | awk '{ print $4 }'`

Comment: I forgot to edit the text. You should be using `$(...)` instead of backquotes, regardless of what the OP is using.